# Kendo UI detail grid expansion on row click

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-kendo

I am using Kendo UI Grid master detail template like in this docs http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular , I am able to get the template by clicking in the hierarchy cell, I want to know if there is some easy way to expand the detail template by clicking anywhere on row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To do that you can follow these steps:

1. Add `k-on-change="handleChange(kendoEvent)"` to **trigger** the function when we select any row,
2. dont forget to add `k-rebind="gridOptions.selectable"`,
3. and i also prefer `<div kendo-grid="grid"></div>` so later on we can
   **select the grid instance**
4. create `$scope.handleChange = function(kendoEvent){....}`to handle the event
5. and finally here is a [kendo dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iFEGu) example from yours that i've modified

EDIT:

1. As per your comment, you simply close all expanded row first then you can open the one which is selected. Add this `$scope.grid.collapseRow($scope.grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row"));` before `$scope.grid.expandRow($scope.grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row.k-state-selected"));`. Updated [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iFEGu/2)

Comment: can we close the previous detail row, when we expand other row?